# Cakephp 4.0 How to do authentication with Outlook Oauth2?

Tags: php, authentication, cakephp, oauth-2.0, cakephp-4.x

So I've successfully been able to implement redirecting to **Outlook** and getting a users access and refresh tokens. I implemented this code in a controller called `AuthController` through route `/auth/login` and call back `/auth/authorize` and then a function is called in the **UsersTable class** which creates the user if it doesn't already exist.

I'm struggling with where to store this data afterwards, so that I can access it on every request and ensure the user is authenticated. I see they've deprecated AuthComponent, so I'm wondering how to fit this into `CakePHP` given its current iteration.

I've seen the Authentication and Authorization plugins, but I can't see a way to fit these into this flow.

Any help would be appreciated.